# Updating the cluster ID/name in a HA HDFS setup

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I need to update "dfs.nameservices" in a running HDFS setup in HA. Just changing the property results in the journalnodes complaining on startup and no master being elected. To note that I do have data that I'd wish to not lose, so reformatting is probably not the answer.

HBase is also running atop this HDFS setup, do I need to pay special attention to anything there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I ended up managing to do this by:

1. Stopping all the HDFS processes on the cluster
2. Update "fs.defaultFS" in core-file.xml, and all the properties in hdfs-site.xml that mentioned the old "dfs.nameservices" value.
3. Start all the journalnodes
4. Run "hdfs namenode -initializeSharedEdits" on a namenode
5. Run "hdfs zkfc -formatZK" on a namenode
6. Startup all the HDFS processes again